# Como fazer um Hello World simples usando convenções em C?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, x64

Conhecendo um pouco das convenções em C e da generalização de código que ele pode nos proporcionar, tentei implementar o meu "Hello World":

```
global main
extern printf

section .data
helloworld db 'Hello World',0

section .text
main:
    push helloworld
    call printf
    ret
```

Logo seguido por
`nasm -fwin64 test.asm` e 
`gcc test.obj`.
A compilação está perfeita. Como não conheço muito de Assembly (apenas um pouco de linguagens de mais alto nível), não vejo o que está errado. O que acontece com o meu programa? Por que isto acontece? Como consertar isso?

PS: Máquina rodando Windows 8, CPU Intel i3 64 bits e *linker* MinGW64. Por simples, quero dizer "sem convenções WinAPI".

Comment: Neste link há um [exemplo](http://mcdermottcybersecurity.com/articles/windows-x64-shellcode) para ambiente Windows 64 bits.

Answer (score 4):

Toda função deve ter seu próprio stack frame, isso faz parte da convenção de funções. Assim, como `main` é uma função, deve iniciar o stack frame com `push ebp` e `mov ebp, esp` e terminar com `leave`. O motivo de você ter que fazer isso com `main` é porque ela **não** é a função principal do seu executável. Na verdade existirá outra, provida pelo compilador, que vai chamar `main`. No Windows seria `WinMain` enquanto que no Linux é a `_start`. Então o código precisa ser assim:

```
global main
extern printf

section .data
helloworld db 'Hello World',0 

section .text
main:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
    push    helloworld
    call    printf
    leave              ; Equivalente a "pop ebp"
    mov     eax, 0     ; Retorne 0
    ret
```

**Mas** você também tem interesse no uso do código em x64. Desse jeito não vai funcionar. A convenção para passagem de argumentos em x86 numéricos (ou ponteiros como é o caso) é adicionar-los na stack. Mas no caso do x64 a convenção muda para usar os seguintes registradores para os 6 primeiros parâmetros: `rdi`, `rsi`, `rdx`, `rcx`, `r8` e `r9`. Do sétimo em diante, precisará por na stack como usual. Então o código fica assim:

```
global main
extern printf

section .data
helloworld db 'Hello World',0 

section .text
main:
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     rdi, helloworld
    call    printf
    leave
    mov     rax, 0     ; Retorne 0
    ret
```

Vale notar, no entanto, que sistemas diferentes ou arquiteturas diferentes podem mudar essas convenções. Precisará sempre escolher exatamente qual é o seu sistema alvo e pesquisa as convenções dele.

Comment: @OP, é melhor você rever os exemplos, declarar o Hello World na variável helloworld, globalizar o main (undefined reference to WinMain) e declarar o printf como externo, se não ele não associa as funções com o arquivo binário.

Comment: @LucasHenrique Havia considerado como snipets e não códigos completos compilaveis. De qualquer forma corrigido.

Comment: @OP me desculpe, não sabia que considerava assim. De qualquer maneira, esqueci de dizer no outro comentário que ele está dando crash. `nasm -fwin64 test.asm -o test.o` `gcc test.o` `a` = "O programa parou de funcionar", etc etc etc. O que será que acontece?

Comment: Com o segundo código? Verificarei assim que chegar em casa com um compilador de verdade.

Comment: qual foi seu resultado?

Comment: @OP Andei olhando na internet e vi que são apenas 4 argumentos: rcx, rdx, r8 e r9. O resto é *push*ado ao stack. Isso está correto?

Comment: @LucasHenrique De fato a convenção difere e é altamente dependente do sistema. No Windows são usados rcx, rdx, r8 e r9. Mas em todos os outros sistemas Unix, 6 registradores são usados. Seja como for, a melhor forma é definir um sistema e uma arquitetura alvo, e depois pesquisar a convenção desse par. Aqui uma boa tabela: [**List of x86 calling conventions**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#List_of_x86_calling_conventions), observe as últimas linhas.

Comment: @OP como é possível rdi = helloworld, sends que rdi só tem 64 bits?

Comment: @LucasHenrique Você passa para a função um ponteiro para aquela memória, não os dados em si. Então fica `rdi = &helloworld`.